# Can not use compose inspector in Android Studio (Flamingo 2022.2.1)

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, layout-inspector

[image: Screenshot]

The device's network is working, but as the screenshot shows, I can't connect to the URL: `maven.google.com`, causing the compose checker to not work properly.

I tried to modify the version for older versions of Compose but it did not solve the problem.

Can I set up the URL or other solution in some way so that I can use compose inspector?

Comment: I am guessing you are accessing from China? If that is the case, a lot of sites are blocked there. You may have to use VPN or alternative options to access the artifacts. Kindly comment if this is not the case.

Comment: @Abhimanyu why we should using VPN ? i faced same issue, when i using VPN the issue is solved. btw im currently in SouthEast Asia

Comment: @Yuba, Some sites may not be accessible to download the artifacts in all regions. I am aware of some sites being blocked in China. Google provides alternate sites for some such regions like [this](https://developers.google.com/china).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What I found was that the layout inspector would stop working when I used 'Compose Navigation' library with version '2.7.0-beta02'. The layout inspector started working again when I changed the navigation library version to '2.6.0'.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34721805)

Answer (score 0):

Downloading the last version which is Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 at the moment worked for me.